# Does there exist a VNC solution with Audio for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vnc

I have two Windows 7 machines: one is a laptop that I use regularly and the other is a desktop that's hooked up to a large TV and some nice speakers.  I want to use VNC to project my laptop onto the large screen.  For movies and presentations and whatnot.

I know there are plenty of programs that will handle the video, but what about audio?  Based on my searches, only Windows Remote Desktop supports audio -- but it requires the server device to be logged out. This is no good, since my laptop is the server in this case and I want to use its mouse and keyboard!

Answer (score 3):

VNCs are in general not meant for streaming, you should [natively stream with VLC](http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/) instead.

As for presentations, why not copy the file over and run it on the remote desktop?

Comment: Good suggestions, but I really just want a wireless external display. I'm not looking to have an extra keyboard and mouse sitting on my coffee table.  I could eliminate the desktop's role entirely by running an HDMI cable between the TV and my laptop -- but then the solution is no longer wireless.

Comment: @nialsh: You don't need those at your coffee table if you do what I said? :/